# Azure ILB ASE with Application Gateway and path based routing

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-application-gateway

Following situation:

there is an ILB ASE with one App Service Plan running 3 different Web Apps.
I would like to use Azure Application Gateway and its path based routing capability to route to these different Web Apps. Is it event possible?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a timely post because I have almost the exact same question.  We 3 websites in our ILBASE, one is the UI, one is an API app and one is a Function App.  We want the ui to resolve to `https://ourapp.company.com`.  We want the api app to be accessible via `https://ourapp.company.com/apiapp` and the Function app to be accessible via `https://ourapp.company.com/function`.  Not sure if this is possible or not.  The link that @iDustBin provided does not really address doing this with an ILBASE...which would have a single backendpool.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got a solution for this:

under "***[Configure a web app behind an existing application gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-getstarted-cli)***" they describe how to configure the App GW...the most important part is the parameter -**PickHostNameFromBackendAddress** which kind of takes the host name as it is defined in the backend pool (e.g. app1.myase.local, app2.myase.local etc. these domains are not on the internet but rather inside the VNET only per deployed App Service). Then you need to configure a private DNS zone in the VNET where the App GW and the Apps live. Here is how: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-getstarted-cli then the path based listener works with multiple apps represented by multiple backend pools in the App GW

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to reach different Web-Ressources ? 
For Example:
fqdn:443/web1/
fqdn:443/web2/
fqdn:443/web3/ ?

i think you are looking for: "url based routing" 
please read:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-introduction

For trainings you can easily work with Haproxy and multiy instances.
if a client gets /videos/ -> 10.100.1.1:443/videos/ and if a customer want to reach /images/ -> 10.100.1.2:443/images
please analyse my first config entries:

```
frontend http
acl videos path_end -i /videos/1
acl images path_end -i /images/2 
acl pdf path_end -i /pdf/3 

use_backend srvs_videos    if videos
use_backend srvs_images    if images
use_backend srvs_pdf    if pdf

backend srvs_videos
   balance roundrobin 
   server host1 10.100.1.1:PORT 
   server host2 10.100.1.2:PORT
```

Comment: I am not sure your example applies because with an ILBASE, I believe there would only be a single backendpool since all traffic would be destined for the VIP of the ILBASE.